Why Is Template Reactivity for `useFetch` Data Not Consistently Working?
Background
I’m building an app using Nuxt 3 and Vue 3 (Node v20.18.0). I’m running into a fundamental issue with template reactivity when trying to display data fetched with useFetch. Specifically:

I can log the data from useFetch in <script setup>, and the data is correct.
However, when binding to the fetched data in the template, the expected reactivity doesn’t occur.
Some solutions work (like wrapping the data in computed), but they feel unnecessary for something as fundamental as this.

My Expectations of Vue/Nuxt

Vue 3's reactivity system should handle changes to nested properties automatically.
In the case of Nuxt's useFetch, I expected the returned data.value to work seamlessly with template bindings, such as {{ data.value.title }}.
I didn’t think I’d need computed or other workarounds to display such basic fetched data in a reactive way.

In simpler Vue apps (without Nuxt), I’ve used reactive ref objects, and direct bindings in templates like {{ myRef.value.someProperty }} always worked as expected. So why doesn’t this work here?
Code
Here's the actual code. You can see what I've tried.
<script setup lang="ts">
const route = useRoute();
const initiativeId = route.params.id;
console.log("Route Params: ", initiativeId);

// DATABASE CALL
const { data, status, error } = await useFetch(`/api/initiative/${initiativeId}`, {
  default: () => ({ title: 'Untitled' }),
});

const computedData = computed(() => data.value);

// ✅ All of these print properly
console.log("response status: ", status.value)
console.log("response error: ", error.value)
console.log("response data: ", data.value);
console.log("response data title: ", data.value.title);
</script>

<template>
  <div id="page-root">
    {{ initiativeId }}

    <div>
      <pre>
        ❓ Displays `No Title Availabe`
      </pre>
      <p v-if="pending">Loading...</p>
      <p v-else-if="error">Error loading data.</p>
      <p v-else>
        Title: {{ data?.value?.title || 'No title available' }}
      </p>
    </div>


    <div>
      <pre>
      ❌ DOES NOT WORK - Title is never displayed - not now, not ever, not even 'Untitled'
      </pre>
      Title: {{ data?.value?.title }}
    </div>

    <div>
      <pre>
      ✅ WORKS - Title is displayed
      </pre>
      Title: {{ computedData.title }}
    </div>

    <div>
      Even though I can see all the data here?!
      <pre>{{ data }}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

Current Behavior

What Works:

I can log data.value and its properties (data.value.title) in <script setup>, and they show the correct values.
Using a computed wrapper around data.value resolves the issue in the template.


What Fails:

Binding directly to data?.value?.title in the template renders undefined or fallback text (e.g., No title available).
Even when providing a default value in useFetch, the template doesn’t update reactively for nested properties like data.value.title.


Strange Observations:

Using <pre>{{ data }}</pre> in the template correctly shows the entire fetched object, including the title.
However, accessing data.value.title directly in the same template fails.



Questions

Why is template reactivity for data.value.title failing?

This seems like a fundamental part of Vue’s reactivity system, so I’m not sure why I need computed for it to work.


Is this an issue with Nuxt’s useFetch?

Could Nuxt be optimizing reactivity in a way that breaks expected behavior for deep properties?


Am I misusing useFetch?

Is there a better way to fetch data in Nuxt 3 to avoid this issue entirely?


Is this a known issue?

I couldn’t find documentation addressing this specific behavior. Should I file a bug report?



Environment Details

Vue Version: 3.x (Nuxt default)
Nuxt Version: 3.x
Node Version: v20.18.0
Other Info: The issue occurs in both development and production modes.

Summary
I want to understand what’s going on here, not just fix the immediate issue. This feels like a core misunderstanding of how Vue’s reactivity works with Nuxt’s useFetch. Any guidance or clarification would be greatly appreciated!

One question at a time, please. https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions

It's all related to how to display data on a template or SFC as there are multiple ways to do it. I'm just trying to figure what is the "right" way to do it.

Barring anything else, seeing .value in the template right away jumps out at me as being an issue (unless it's your own internal property coincidentally named "value").

Current LTS of Node is v22 so that you know.

refs are automatically unwrapped when referenced in templates, please remove .value in the template:
<template>
  <div>
    Title: {{ data?.title }}
  </div>
</template>

Ref: https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#reactivity

Volar/ESlint should indeed inform you of such thing.
